# Dealing with declaring class twice in PHP

Tags: php, oop

I am using the 3rd party ostickets application.  Line 17 of include/class.passwd.php includes the code `require_once(INCLUDE_DIR.'PasswordHash.php');` which creates an object using `class PasswordHash {...}`.

My problem is I use the 3rd party class PashwordHash earlier in my script independently of ostickets, and my first use of the PasswordHash needs to come before when used with ostickets.

Since ostickets comes as a package, it includes its own copy of PasswordHash.php, thus `required_once` doesn't prevent the class from being declared twice.  I would rather not modify the osticket package using something like `if(!class_exists('PasswordHash')){require_once(INCLUDE_DIR.'PasswordHash.php');}` as this will cause problems if I upgrade ostickets and forget to make the changes.

I would also rather not modify the first file which includes the PasswordHash class by changing the class name again to allow future upgrades without problems.

My options as I see them...

1. Modify one of the 3rd party libraries even though I would rather not.
2. Somehow declare the class when I first use it, and somehow "destroy it" and then go on with my business with ostickets.  I don't think this is possible, but am not sure.
3. Create a namespace when I first use PasswordHash.  Is this a viable option, and if so, how?
4. Maybe something else which I have not thought of?

Thanks

Comment: You stomach is right about not wanting to modify 3rdparty code. Go for namespaces.

Comment: @arkascha.  I've never dealt with namespace.  Does it occur when creating the class (and thus requiring me to modify my first version)?  Any pointers?

Comment: See http://php.net/namespace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed what namespaces are for:

```
<?php

  namespace NiceNamespaceName;

  class PasswordHash
  {
  }

?>
```

Then you can use it as such:

```
<?php
  $hash = new \NiceNamespaceName\PasswordHash();
?>
```

Comment: Does `namespace NiceNamespaceName;` need to be in the file has the class, or could it be beforehand?  Something like `namespace NiceNamespaceName; require_once('PasswordHash.php`); $obj=new PasswordHash();`

Comment: @user1032531 namespaces are per-file, so yes you would need to include in this in the source file that contains the class declaration

Comment: @DaveRandom.  So one way or another, I need to modify a 3rd party library, no?

Comment: @user1032531 No, you only need to modify the version of that class that you include in your own code and put that in a namespace, and reference the namespaced version from you code. The version that osticket ships with will remain in the global namespace, but yours will be in a different one, so they will no longer collide. To be honest this is one of the problems that autoloading is used to solve (if the class exists, the code to go and find it will never be invoked). However if osticket does not use an autoloader it doesn't help you here